# Will re-populating a password field in a form be a security issue?

Tags: html, security

I am wondering if I should re-populate the (masked) password field in a form when other fields don't validate. I have seen both on the web where the form would either:

1. re-populate the masked password field
2. empty the password field, so the user needs to put it in again (even though it was valid)

What is your best practice? Does re-populating the password field indicate a security hole? Usability-wise I would prefer to re-populate the field and not have the user re-enter it.

Comment: If you do not serve the form document via HTTPS, then **absolutely NO**.

Comment: presumably you'll not put the actual password in. since you only stored its hash how could you anyway.

Comment: He's talking about a scenario in which a user is logging in, enters the correct password, but the wrong email/username. In that case, he wants the form to be submitted and rendered again with the same information still held in the inputs, including the password.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One option if you want to do this, is not actually send the password plain-text, but a random token.  Since it's a password field, the user won't be able to tell (except for the length).  Then, store the hashed password and token in the session.  When the user submits the form, if the password field is the same as the stored token, use the stored password hash.  Otherwise use the submitted password. This solves the cache issues (Since the random token will have no meaning in requests by other sessions).  That way you never need to store or transmit the raw password after the initial form submission...

Comment: i have thought about this, too. if i additionally encrypt the stored password in the session it will be even more secure. i guess that would be a suitable solution wouldn't it?

Comment: @Frank: Absolutely.  You don't even need to store it in the session plain text.  Store the salted hash.  And that way if the token matches, just store it in the db. If not, throw it away...  Good alternative (I'll edit it in)

Comment: But what random token would you use? Especially: A random token of what length?

Comment: same length as the original password, so the user sees the same amount of masked characters in the password field

Comment: @Gordon: Personally, I would use a long random token (at least 32 characters for enough entropy).  Most users won't notice this (I've seen this done on other projects/websites).  If you must use a fixed length (same as password), then I would suggest using most ascii chars for the token (33 - 125) so you have a fair bit of entropy...

Answer (score 2):

Re-populating it is much more comfortable for the user.

However, if the form is submitted in the classic way (i.e. with a full page reload, not via AJAX) you risk the html containing the password being cached. With proper headers you can lower/remove that risk though. Using HTTPs is also really important in that case. It completely prevents HTTP proxies from caching it and the local browser cache usually honors nocache headers (and even if not, it's not a big issue if caching happens on the local machine).

All in all, I usually prefer not having to enter the password again just because another field (e.g. a crappy captcha) was incorrrect.. but in a high-security environment you don't want to re-populate the password field unless you are using AJAX and don't have to actually send back the entered password.

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not (if done right).

- An attacker in the network (i.e. between browser and server) will have seen the password the client sent. If you're using HTTPS, you **must** use it for the form as well as its target.
- A browser-side attacker could have registered a listener on the password field or intercepted the request.
- A third-party attacker could try to fetch the filled-out page from a proxy the user's using. Set appropriate `Cache-Control` headers to prevent the page from being cached.

Comment: @Frank Michel By respecting the conditions listed in the answer, i.e. use HTTPS for everything if you use it and set appropriate cache headers.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, clear your password fields and don't re-populate them. Don't compromise security for usability.

Answer (score 0):

It's a security issue on shared computers since the password will be visible in cleartext when viewing the html source. Not only in an active browser window, but also in any diskbased cache.

I would personally go with OpenID instead of requiring the user to invent yet another username+password pair to remember (which also affect usability to the better).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send the actual password (or anything derived from it) from the server to the client in order to re-populate it, it's a major security hole.

If all you do is save the password locally on the client until the form submit validates (by not reloading the page, eg via javascript), then it seems fine to me.

Comment: If the server just sends back (via https) the same string the user typed originally, how is there a "major security hole"?

Comment: Over HTTPS would probably be ok, although theoretically it allows for repeated plaintext attacks (same plaintext encrypted multiple times). Not that I know of any such vulnerability in SSL. There is no question that the best would be not to send it all.