# How to properly escape password field on HTML form?

Tags: php

Input field for password usually accepts a wide range of characters compared to text inputs. The normal way of escaping an input on HTML form involves using `htmlspecialchars($_POST['content'])` on the input contents.

What if, in the scenario of a failed validation of a password update process, I require the new password to repopulate on the HTML form? Something like `'> yeah` would have caused the form to malfunction and using `htmlspecialchars` would produce a totally different password.

Any suggestions?

The html portion as shown:

```
<INPUT type=password name=password1 value=''&gt;&lt;script&gt;try' size=15 maxlength=15>
```

The corresponding php code:

```
function h($str) {echo htmlspecialchars($str);}
echo "<INPUT type=password name=password1 value='", h(@$_POST['password1']), "' size=15 maxlength=15>";
```

Blank is shown in the form input field.

**UPDATE**

The problem lies with my `htmlspecialchars` which does not escape single quotes by default. Now adding the `ENT_QUOTES` parameters allow the single quote to be escaped and solve my problem. deceze and CodeCaster are right that `htmlspecialchars` does not change the password. Thanks all.

Comment: the escaping is something you need when you save the data in your database (and your should encrypt the password).. and htmlspecialchars is not escaping characters, it just converts some charaters to entities.. leava the user input the way it is until you save it in your database and then use mysql_real_escape_string or PDO what fits your needs

Comment: @ mishu, that i know. Not the point i am asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `htmlspecialchars` would not produce a totally different password. It would produce `value="&gt; yeah"` which, when parsed by the browser, is read as `> yeah`. Password fields are not in any way special in the treatment of special or non-special characters.

Comment: but when I resend, won't it be `&gt; yeah` instead of the original `> yeah`?

Comment: No. It only needs to be escaped to avoid ambiguous syntax for the HTML parser. The parser will read it as `>` and treat the value as `>` henceforth.

Comment: May I recommend you read [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)?

Comment: when i use `htmlspecialchars`, the password field becomes blank though there are values in it.

Comment: Show us the code and the resulting raw HTML. You're doing something wrong somewhere.

Comment: you forgot that I have a single quote in front `'> yeah`

Answer (score 3):

Separate display logic from data logic.

Before you want to display data on an html page, use `htmlspecialchars()`. If you're about to store it in a database, use the appropriate sql escaping method (like `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

By the way, if an input element contains for example `&gt`, it will be seen as `>` when posted;

Comment: you mean php will automatically know that it is `>` when posted? Ok, but that doesn't solve the form being malfunction because of the `'>`

Comment: It won't malfunction, as long as you use double quotes for enclosing the value of an element (say,`value="'&gt;&quot;"` will work).

Comment: @ CodeCaster, if using double quote works for `'>`, would it work for `">`?

Comment: I see... Because I am echoing the html statement with double quotes, that's why i am using single quotes for html properties. Seems that I have to change.

Comment: using ENT_QUOTES in `htmlspecialchars()` would also solve my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `htmlspecialchars_decode()` to decode your password.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php

I however don't see the reason of repopulating the password input if the password was wrong, nor do I think it's safe. I also hope you're not saving passwords in text format in your database.

Comment: lets say the old password was wrong and new password I need to key in twice.

Comment: You should hardly ever need `htmlspecialchars_decode` for data received from the browser...

Answer (score 1):

> The normal way of escaping an input on HTML form involves using htmlspecialchars($_POST['content']) on the input contents.

That's not normal but rather wrong way.
Escaping HTML is normally used for *output*, not for input.

> What if, in the scenario of a failed validation of a password update process, I require the new password to repopulate on the HTML form?

That's dangerous practice and most services ask a user to re-enter password on such occasion.

> to repopulate on the HTML form?

Here goes HTML escaping. Unlike other cases, HTML escaping is **obligatory** here, when you are to populate form values.

Comment: (1) Am I wrong to classify what the user keyed in the input form field as an input? (2) [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774607/will-re-populating-a-password-field-in-a-form-be-a-security-issue) is what others think on SO. (3) Yes, agree. Anyway I got my answer already. Thanks.

Comment: I were not answering your question but rather clarifying thing. Everything come from the user side is called input. And it has absolutely nothing to do with HTML escaping. There is no HTML on the server side - so, nothing to escape. On the other hand, output is sometimes going to the browser that interpert HTML, so, there can be a need to escape it.